# Upload a file to Google Drive with Python and API v3 always create a new Folder and ignores the passed parent folder_id

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-drive-api

I'm writing a python script to upload a backup zip from a server to a Drive Workspace account (I'm using Server to Server Auth).
In a day there are 2 backups zips to upload in a sub-folder. The path where to upload onto Drive is:

ROOT > COMPANY_NAME > TODAY_DATE_FOLDER

In `TODAY_DATE_FOLDER` I expect to obviously find the 2 backup zips.
Instead, inside `COMPANY_NAME` I found 2 `TODAY_DATE_FOLDER`, with one zip into one folder and the other zip into the other folder.
I tested to upload a third zip file and the script will create a third folder TODAY_DATE_FOLDER with the third zip.
My goal to achieve with this script is to create a `TODAY_DATE_FOLDER` and upload the first file, then upload in the same `TODAY_DATE_FOLDER` the second zip file

**Edit**
I tried to run the script via command line, *seems* work properly with the command:
`python3.7 /_script/py-uploader/main.py -p "/path/to/file/to/upload/file.ext" -c "COMPANY_NAME"`
Where the `args` are: -p the path to the file to upload, and -c is the arg that I pass to know in which folder to upload -> `ROOT > COMPANY_NAME`.

By running this from the command line the script create only one `TODAY_DATE_FOLDER` inside the `COMPANY_NAME` with both the backup zips. **This is the outcome I am looking for**

I run this python script from a *bash script* with the same command above:
...
`python3.7 /_script/py-uploader/main.py -p "$FILE_TO_UPLOAD" -c "$COMPANY_NAME"`
...

The bash script is launched from the *crontab*

Here's the code:
**Update**
Github's repo:
https://github.com/andreazanetti92/py-uploader

main.py

```py
query_result=query_files(service=service, 
                         query=f"'{GDRIVE_ID_BACKUP_FOLDER}' in parents and name contains '{TODAY_DATE}' and trashed=false and mimeType='{MIME_TYPE_GOOGLE_FOLDER}'")
print(query_result)
if query_result is not None and len(query_result) > 0:
  print("\n IF TODAY Folder exists \n")
  print("\n" + GDRIVE_ID_BACKUP_FOLDER + "\n")
  TODAY_FOLDER_ID=query_result[0].get('id')
  print("TODAY_FOLDER_ID: " + TODAY_FOLDER_ID)
  upload_file_to_folderID(service=service, file_to_upload=FILEPATH_TO_UPLOAD, mime_type=MIME_TYPE_ZIP,   folder_id=TODAY_FOLDER_ID)
else:
  print("\n IF DOES NOT EXISTS the FOLDER \n")
  print(GDRIVE_ID_BACKUP_FOLDER)
  result = create_folder(service=service, folder_name=TODAY_DATE, parent_folder=GDRIVE_ID_BACKUP_FOLDER)
  if result is not None:
    print("\n IF IT WAS CREATED THE TODAY FOLDER \n")
    print("\n" + result + '\n')
    GDRIVE_ID_BACKUP_FOLDER=result.get('id')
    upload_file_to_folderID(service=service, file_to_upload=FILEPATH_TO_UPLOAD, mime_type=MIME_TYPE_ZIP, folder_id=GDRIVE_ID_BACKUP_FOLDER)
  else:
    log_error_to_file(f"Something wrong occur when creating the folder with name {TODAY_DATE}")


def create_folder(folder_name, parent_folder=None):
 file_metadata={
      'name': folder_name,
      'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder',
      'parents': [parent_folder]
    }
 item=service.files().create(body=file_metadata, fields='id, name').execute()
 if item is not None:
   log_info_to_file(f"Folder with NAME: {item.get('name')} and ID: {item.get('id')} was created successfully")
   return item
 else:
   log_error_to_file(f"Something wrong in the creation of the folder {folder_name}")
   return None


def upload_file_to_folderID:
  if file_to_upload is not None and os.path.exists(file_to_upload) and folder_id is not None:
    fileName=file_to_upload.rsplit('/', 1)
    file_metadata={
        'name': fileName[1], 
        'parents': [folder_id]
        }
    media=MediaFileUpload(file_to_upload, mimetype=mime_type)
    item=service.files().create(
        body=file_metadata,
        media_body=media, 
        fields='id,name'
        ).execute()
    if item is not None:
      log_info_to_file(f"File {item.get('name')} successfully uploaded to folder with ID {folder_id}")
      return item
    else:
      log_error_to_file(f"Something went wrong on uploading file: {file_to_upload} to {folder_id}")
      return None
  else:
    log_error_to_file(f"You must provide all the arguments")


def query_files(service, query):
  files= list()
  page_token=None
  response=None
  while True:
    response=service.files().list(q=query, fields='nextPageToken, '
                                          'files(id, name)', pageToken=page_token).execute()
    for file in response.get('files', []):
      log_info_to_file(F'Found file: {file.get("name")}, {file.get("id")}')
      print(F'File found: {file.get("name")}, {file.get("id")}')
    #files=response.get('files', [])
    files.extend(response.get('files', []))
    page_token = response.get('nextPageToken', None)
    if page_token is None:
      break
 if len(files) > 0:
   return files
 else:
   return None
```

Comment: Please include a minimal example that reproduces the issue. Please visit [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) have some tips on how to write a question, so the community will be able to help you out in a better way.

Comment: Hello, I updated my question by adding a link to a github repo with all the code. Obviously you need to have a G Workspace account, `create a service account` and `download the credentials`.